# How to properly pack regex that contains both double as well as single quotes into a variable and evaluate it in Bash?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, email, escape-characters

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) stackoverflow question gives the following regex for RFC5322 compliant e-mail format matching:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

The regex contains both single as well as double quotes that must be matched.

What's the proper, portable Bash way to store that into a variable and then evaluate it?

My approach would be to use single quotes, then end the single-quoted part before each single-quote of the regex, add an escaped single-quote, and then continue with single-quoted rest, which would lead to the following (note the replacement of all `'` in the original regex with `'\''` as well as addition of one `'` at the start and end of the complete regex :

```
regex='(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'\''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'\''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'
```

typing `echo $regex` (as well as `echo "$regex$"`) will then output the regex string exactly as defined in the original link.
Then, to evaluate it:

```
if [[ "$email" =~ $regex ]] ; then
    echo "This is an RFC5322 compliant e-mail address"
else
    echo "This is NOT an RFC5322 compliant e-mail address"
fi
```

however, just testing this with a plain e-mail address `email="john.doe@domain.com"` fails (it also fails if using `if [[ "$email" =~ "$regex" ]] ; then`)

What's wrong and what is the best/cleanest way of doing this in bash? (if someone's gonna say don't use bash, unfortunately that's a prerequisite and so is RFC5322 conformity)

Comment: Because your regex is Perl based which you are trying to use in bash. Either run in Perl or convert the regex to bash.

Comment: @guest_7 thank you, how do I do that?

Comment: I have added a minimal code to run. You may try now.

Comment: Using `foo='ain'\''t so'` (or `bar=$'don\'t do it'`), is exactly the way to put single-quotes in a string. But here, that's the least of your problems... Apart from using PCRE features and ranges like `\x01-\x09`, I think these comments on that SO post are noteworthy: _"validating it per the RFC tells you absolutely nothing about whether that address actually exists at the supplied domain, or whether the person entering the address is its true owner."_, and _"Confirmation tokens are the only way to know you got the address of the person entering it."_.

Comment: Anyway, even though that uses PCRE `(?:...)` groups, _on a really quick look_, it looks to me that's the only PCRE feature it uses, so it could be changed to an ERE by just replacing those with `(...)`. The range expressions may be a bit of a problem in Bash since they're locale-dependant, but it seems to work if you force `LC_ALL=C` (`LC_COLLATE` is probably the relevant one)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you go about doing it with `perl` in `bash`.

- place the regex on the environment tray of Perl.
- pipe the e-mail address on the stdin of Perl.
- then try matching in perl and exit with an inverse status since bash n perl have complementary sense of success.
- rest is your stuff.

```
printf '%s\n' "$email" \
| _regex_="$regex"     \
     perl -0777 -ne 'chop;exit !/$ENV{_regex_}/'

if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
    echo "This is an RFC5322 compliant e-mail address"
else
    echo "This is NOT an RFC5322 compliant e-mail address"
fi
```